# Creating a custom code analysis rule for a custom grammar, and test it: howto?

Tags: java, sonarqube

Based on the minimal C parser example, and using the following dependencies:

```
compile(group: "org.codehaus.sonar.sslr", name: "sslr", version: "1.20");
compile(group: "org.codehaus.sonar.sslr", name: "sslr-testing-harness",
    version: "1.20");
compile(group: "org.codehaus.sonar.sslr", name: "sslr-examples",
    version: "1.20");
```

I have created a completely useless grammar with completely useless tokens and run a completely useless main() which works fine (WARNING: lots of code):

```
// Operators.java
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
public enum Operators
    implements TokenType
{
    ADD("+");

    private final String value;

    Operators(final String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }


    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return name();
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasToBeSkippedFromAst(final AstNode node)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// NumLiteral.java
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
public enum NumLiteral
    implements TokenType
{
    LITERAL;

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return name();
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue()
    {
        return name();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasToBeSkippedFromAst(final AstNode node)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// ExampleLexer.java
public final class ExampleLexer
{
    private ExampleLexer()
    {
        throw new Error("nice try!");
    }

    public static Lexer create()
    {
        return Lexer.builder()
            .withChannel(regexp(NumLiteral.LITERAL, "\\d++"))
            .withChannel(new PunctuatorChannel(Operators.values()))
            .build();
    }
}

// ExampleGrammar.java
public enum ExampleGrammar
    implements GrammarRuleKey
{
    EXPRESSION,
    ;

    public static Grammar create()
    {
        final LexerfulGrammarBuilder builder = LexerfulGrammarBuilder.create();

        builder.rule(EXPRESSION).is(builder.sequence(NumLiteral.LITERAL,
            Operators.ADD, NumLiteral.LITERAL));

        builder.setRootRule(EXPRESSION);

        return builder.build();
    }
}

// ExampleParser.java
public final class ExampleParser
{
    private ExampleParser()
    {
        throw new Error("nice try!");
    }

    public static Parser<Grammar> create()
    {
        return Parser.builder(ExampleGrammar.create())
            .withLexer(ExampleLexer.create())
            .build();
    }
}

// ExampleToolkit.java
public final class ExampleToolkit
{
    private static final class ExampleConfigurationModel
        extends AbstractConfigurationModel
    {
        @Override
        public Parser doGetParser()
        {
            return ExampleParser.create();
        }

        @Override
        public List<Tokenizer> doGetTokenizers()
        {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        @Override
        public List<ConfigurationProperty> getProperties()
        {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        final ConfigurationModel model = new ExampleConfigurationModel();
        final Toolkit toolkit = new Toolkit("foo", model);
        toolkit.run();
    }
}
```

This shows a window, I can input text, it tokenizes correctly etc.

However, in order to render the thing a little less useless, now I want to implement a rule on this all. I did program one:

```
public final class ExampleRule
    extends SquidCheck<Grammar>
{
    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        subscribeTo(NumLiteral.LITERAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitNode(final AstNode astNode)
    {
    }
}
```

The code of the rule is not even written yet; but that's not the point.

The point is: how do I test the rule at all?

This means I need to be able to:

- parse an input with the grammar;
- register my tested rule to the tokenized parsing result;
- check that my rule behaves the way I want.

Unfortunately, the sonar docs are poor on all three points; while there is existing code for already existing languages, no documentation exists which guides you through the process of doing it yourself.

So, how do you test the above, and, more importantly, how do you make it so that you can extend your tests when the grammar itself is extended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the documentation is shoddy at best, I decided to look through the source code and I found that you just use

```
AstNode a = ExampleParser.create().parser("source code to parse");
```

Or

```
AstNode a = ExampleParser.create().parser(new File("path/to/source"));
```

Now you can use your `ExampleRule.visitNode` directly on the [`AstNode`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sslr/blob/master/sslr-core/src/main/java/com/sonar/sslr/api/AstNode.java) you got above.  The issue with doing that though is that it won't recurse like the intended API would, for that you need to use the [`AstWalker.walkAndVisit`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sslr/blob/master/sslr-core/src/main/java/com/sonar/sslr/impl/ast/AstWalker.java#L65) and that is hidden in the implementation.

Now in an older version, in order to walk over your `AstNode`, you need to use the `AstScanner` class which does the above steps for you.  You can set up the `AstScanner` like so:

```
SquidAstVisitorContextImpl<Grammar> savci = new SquidAstVisitorContextImpl<Grammar>(new SourceProject("Custom Grammar"));
AstScanner.Builder b = AstScanner.builder(savci);

b.setBaseParser(ExampleParser.create());
b.setCommentAnalyser(new CommentAnalyser {
  @override
  public bool isBlank(String line) {
    return true;
  }
  @override
  public String getContents(String comment) {
    return "";
  }
});
b.setFileMetric(FILES); // I am not sure what a 'Metric' is as both the documentation and source are unclear on that, you may have to experiment with this value.

b.withSquidAstVisitor(new ExampleRule());

AstScanner<Grammar> as = b.build();
as.scanFile(new File("path/to/source"));
```

Then, to check what the scanner has collected, you just use `as.getIndex()` to return an instance of `org.sonar.squid.api.SourceCodeSearchEngine`.  I would pull up some more info on that part but I currently don't have the time to do so, I may edit my answer later and follow up on that.

For the more current version though, it appears that the only way to properly walk over the ast like a traditional visitor pattern is to use the [`AstWalker`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sslr/blob/master/sslr-core/src/main/java/com/sonar/sslr/impl/ast/AstWalker.java) class.

As I am not familiar enough with Sonar as a framework, I don't know much about its testing harness, though this ought to be enough for some rough testing routines.

Comment: Yes, I could get at least a basic mockito verify() to run. But then after that, no idea how to see the collected error messages if any :/

Comment: @fge It doesn't collect any error messages.  If there are any error messages then you need to set them up yourself.

Comment: OK, I found out how to do it... You have to `spy()` the context you pass to the `AstScanner` and check that the rule will call `.create*Violation()`. Meh. And all of this is of course not documented :/

Comment: @fge And the worst part was trying to ``git grep`` across multiple versions, cause of course they can't just deprecate their API, they have to delete the whole file... I don't know much about sonar, but the sslr API is pretty unusable...

Comment: OK, accepted your answer; it pretty much does the job! I'll complement that with an answer with my findings. Thanks again!

Comment: @fge no problem, I even made it community wiki so it'll be easier.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so first of all [thanks to @randomusername](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28864046/1093528) for all the code digging and subsequent pointers.

My goal being to test rules, the `AstWalker` class is indeed the central class.

So, first of all, the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile(group: "org.codehaus.sonar.sslr", name: "sslr", version: "1.20");
    compile(group: "org.codehaus.sonar.sslr", name: "sslr-examples",
        version: "1.20");
    compile(group: "org.codehaus.sonar.sslr-squid-bridge",
        name: "sslr-squid-bridge", version: "2.5.3");
    testCompile(group: "org.testng", name: "testng", version: "6.8.21") {
        exclude(group: "org.apache.ant", module: "ant");
        exclude(group: "com.google.inject", module: "guice");
        exclude(group: "junit", module: "junit");
        exclude(group: "org.beanshell", module: "bsh");
        exclude(group: "org.yaml", module: "snakeyaml");
    };
    testCompile(group: "org.mockito", name: "mockito-core", version: "1.10.19");
    testCompile(group: "org.assertj", name: "assertj-core", version: "1.7.1");
    testCompile(group: "org.codehaus.sonar.sslr", name: "sslr-testing-harness",
        version: "1.20");
}
```

The modified code of the rule to actually do something:

```
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
public class ExampleRule
    extends SquidCheck<Grammar>
{
    @VisibleForTesting
    static final String MESSAGE = "0 in an addition";

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        subscribeTo(NumLiteral.LITERAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitNode(final AstNode astNode)
    {
        final String value = astNode.getTokenValue();
        final int i = Integer.parseInt(value);

        if (i != 0)
            return;

        final SquidAstVisitorContext<Grammar> context = getContext();

        context.createLineViolation(this, MESSAGE, astNode);
    }
}
```

And now the test; two things are needed:

- the rule must be initialized by calling `init()`; it appears that this would be the job of an `AstScanner` but I don't use one (I don't need one);
- there must be a `SquidAstVisitorContext` since this is where rules will inject messages.

I mock the context, and I use mockito's `ArgumentCaptor` to check that the message is actually what I expect it to be:

```
public class ExampleRuleTest
{
    private SquidCheck<Grammar> rule;
    private SquidAstVisitorContext<Grammar> context;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void init()
    {
        rule = spy(new ExampleRule());
        context = mock(SquidAstVisitorContext.class);
        doReturn(context).when(rule).getContext();
        // We need that; otherwise the list of tokens isn't accounted for
        rule.init();
    }

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        final AstNode node = ExampleParser.create().parse("0+2");

        final AstWalker walker = new AstWalker(rule);
        walker.walkAndVisit(node);

        final ArgumentCaptor<String> captor
            = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

        verify(context).createLineViolation(same(rule), captor.capture(),
            any(AstNode.class));

        assertThat(captor.getValue()).isEqualTo(ExampleRule.MESSAGE);
    }
}
```